# Bootstrap two column layout and ng-repeat (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a two col layout with ng-repeat.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in items">
       Item: {{item}}
   </div>
</div>
```

This results in the following problem:

[image]

P.S. This problem has been answered before with native CSS cols but I want to do it with bootstrap.

P.S. The solution proposed below is not working.. anyone got any other ideas please?

Answer (score 11):

You'll have to break it into two seperate columns, but it should be pretty easy after that:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: items.length /2: 0">
       Item: {{item}}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: items.length /2: items.length /2">
       Item: {{item}}
   </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! exactly the kind of solution i wanted because everything is handled in the view!

Comment: hi, is there a way to extend it to 3, 4 columns? I know I can always type "col-md-4" and change limit to items.length / 3, but i think it may possible to do so with nested ng-repeats with variable number of cols!

Comment: p.s. sorry one more thing.. i think items.length /2, gets Math.floor and it leaves out the last element. Is it okay to add +1 to it?

Comment: please see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/GdV116QqeawGpVOTHI25?p=preview there are 5 items, but it renders only the first four?

Comment: You're right, should just be able to get around that by adding 1. http://plnkr.co/edit/jkG6B51OBcvXsTNeOz8H?p=preview

Comment: hi, thanks for the update.. now the items are listing randomly, like "item 1" does not have "item 2" after it (it's in the next col) and there is a gap between item 2 and item 5.. please see this: http://embed.plnkr.co/uiyqxf9q02SdbF4q7Myq/

Answer (score 0):

for that i'm taken two tables 
keep bootstrap  styles

```
<table> <tr ng-repeat="cl in codelist" ng-if="$index<codelist.length/2">
                            <td>{{$index}}</td>

                        </tr></table>
<table> <tr ng-repeat="cl in codelist" ng-if="$index>=codelist.length/2">
                            <td>{{$index}}</td>

                        </tr></table>
```

that it show order by ordey 
1  3
2  4
5  6
like this